# Offset of Auto Margin Element Enigma - How to retrieve x & y from canvas element- mouse event

Tags: html, canvas

I have attempted everything but the solution while trying to figure out why I cannot correctly retrieve the x and y position of a mouse down event on a canvas sitting centered on page with auto horizontal margins.

currently:

- I have relative positioning on the containing parent of the canvas as as well as
  for the canvas itself.
- I am subtracting the the offset left & offset top from the mouse
  events .pageX & .pageY

My goal is to return the spot(mouse down) where a user will drag a strokeRect onto the canvas. Im thinking it's a css issue but im stumped.

```
body, header, aside, footer, div, canvas{
    display: block;
    position: relative;
}

canvas {
    z-index: 99;
    background: #996;
}

#canvas-contain{
    height: 600px;
    width: 967px;
    margin: 50px auto;
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 5px 1px #222222;
}

<script>
rect.startX = e.pageX - this.offsetLeft;
rect.startY = e.pageY - this.offsetTop;


function mouseMove(e) {
  if (drag) {
    rect.w = (e.pageX - this.offsetLeft) - rect.startX;
    rect.h = (e.pageY - this.offsetTop) - rect.startY ;
    context.clearRect(0,0,canvas.width,canvas.height);
    draw();
  }

}

function draw() {
  context.strokeRect(rect.startX, rect.startY, rect.w, rect.h);
}

</script>

<body>
    <div id="ramRod">
        <div id="canvas-contain">
            <canvas id="canvas" height="600" width="967"></canvas>
        </div>
        <footer id="footer">
            <div id="left-fb" class="foot-box"></div>
            <div id="right-fb" class="foot-box"></div>
         </footer>
     </div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Here's how to track mouse events on the canvas**

In your code, you'll want to use e.clientX/e.clientY instead of e.pageX/e.pageY

...And a Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/m1erickson/gfzGz/

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="all" href="css/reset.css" /> <!-- reset css -->
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery.min.js"></script>

<style>
    body{ background-color: ivory; }
    canvas{border:1px solid red;}
</style>

<script>
$(function(){

    var canvas=document.getElementById("canvas");
    var ctx=canvas.getContext("2d");

    var canvasOffset=$("#canvas").offset();
    var offsetX=canvasOffset.left;
    var offsetY=canvasOffset.top;

    function handleMouseDown(e){
      canMouseX=parseInt(e.clientX-offsetX);
      canMouseY=parseInt(e.clientY-offsetY);
      $("#downlog").html("Down: "+ canMouseX + " / " + canMouseY);

      // Put your mousedown stuff here

    }

    function handleMouseUp(e){
      canMouseX=parseInt(e.clientX-offsetX);
      canMouseY=parseInt(e.clientY-offsetY);
      $("#uplog").html("Up: "+ canMouseX + " / " + canMouseY);

      // Put your mouseup stuff here
    }

    function handleMouseOut(e){
      canMouseX=parseInt(e.clientX-offsetX);
      canMouseY=parseInt(e.clientY-offsetY);
      $("#outlog").html("Out: "+ canMouseX + " / " + canMouseY);

      // Put your mouseOut stuff here
    }

    function handleMouseMove(e){
      canMouseX=parseInt(e.clientX-offsetX);
      canMouseY=parseInt(e.clientY-offsetY);
      $("#movelog").html("Move: "+ canMouseX + " / " + canMouseY);

      // Put your mousemove stuff here

    }

    $("#canvas").mousedown(function(e){handleMouseDown(e);});
    $("#canvas").mousemove(function(e){handleMouseMove(e);});
    $("#canvas").mouseup(function(e){handleMouseUp(e);});
    $("#canvas").mouseout(function(e){handleMouseOut(e);});

}); // end $(function(){});
</script>

</head>

<body>

    <p id="downlog">Down</p>
    <p id="movelog">Move</p>
    <p id="uplog">Up</p>
    <p id="outlog">Out</p>
    <canvas id="canvas" width=300 height=300></canvas>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Hi Five. Thanks. clientX, now I know.

Comment: Your fiddle is awesome by the way- Thanks for the quality demo of each event.